# How to determine Multilanguage / Localisation Hierarchy

Tags: localization, multilingual

Localisation is an important and tough issue for everyone. While determining localisation keys,  we should avoid duplication, determining text case (uppercase, lowercase, uppercase), articles, singular/plural and suffix/prefix correctly, creating clean hierarchy (according to controller, page, model or category).

Please, share your strategy and lead developers to handle this issue.

Comment: What problem are you facing specifically? This is far too broad to answer.

Comment: I am confused while creating message keys that's why i am looking for recommendation and new ideas.

Comment: @halfer, can you check my anwer, please share your comments with me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to use this strategy. You can comment it to improve.

```
{ case } :: UC - Uppercase
{ case } :: LC - Lowercase
{ case } :: CC - Camelcase
```

**For Specific Keys**

{ category }. { page }. { key }*.{ case }*

*examples*

```
landing.city.title = { param0 } Cheapest Flights

landing.fromto.title = { param0 } - { param1 }  Cheapest Flights
```

**Common or Basic Keys (Enums, Forms)**

{ category }.{ key }*.{ case }*

*examples*

```
  landing.nearestAirports = Nearest Airports
  currency.TRY = TL
  gender.MALE = Male 
  searchForm.from = From
  searchForm.flexibleDates = Flexible Dates
  signinForm.username = Usernmame
  cabinType.ECONOMY = Economy
  passengerDetail.name = Name
  invoice.taxnumber =  Tax Number
```